# How should this expression be changed in order to perform an IF THEN causality?

Tags: sql, sql-server, if-statement, case-statement

I'm trying to get an expression which populates the column `Replacement_Manufacturer` with a random variation of the values from another table if the value in the column `Service_Reaction_Description` equals 'repair with replacement of spare parts'.

(Both columns are within the same table 'dbo.SERVICE_REQUEST'.)

Here's the expression I'm trying to end up with something like that:

```
IF Service_Reaction_Description = 'repair with replacement of spare parts'
THEN UPDATE dbo.SERVICE_TICKE
SET Replacement_Manufacturer = (Select top 1 replacement_manufacturer from dbo.test_data where id = abs(checksum(NewID()))%10)
END IF
```

Answer (score 2):

You're thinking procedurally - you want to update ALL records in the table when that value appears, right?  An `IF` statement will only apply once, and then it will apply to all records in the table.

```
UPDATE dbo.SERVICE_TICKE
SET Replacement_Manufacturer = (Select top 1 replacement_manufacturer from dbo.test_data where id = abs(checksum(NewID()))%10)
WHERE Service_Reaction_Description = 'repair with replacement of spare parts'
```

Comment: Man, I can't believe I didn't catch that. This is the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

You're pretty close. To only execute the `UPDATE` statement when the condition is met, try this:

```
IF Service_Reaction_Description = 'repair with replacement of spare parts'
BEGIN
  UPDATE dbo.SERVICE_TICKE
  SET Replacement_Manufacturer = 
    (Select top 1 replacement_manufacturer 
     from dbo.test_data 
     where id = abs(checksum(NewID()))%10)
END
```

Technically, with a single-statement expression, you don't need the `BEGIN` and `END`, but you do need it whenever you want to include multiple statements within the block, so I find it easier to read and more maintainable to just always include the `BEGIN...END` block.

You also tagged this post with `case-statement`, which is also an option. That would always execute the `UPDATE` statement, but would only replace the field in question when your criterion is met:

```
UPDATE dbo.SERVICE_TICKE
SET Replacement_Manufacturer =
  CASE Service_Reaction_Description 
    WHEN 'repair with replacement of spare parts'
      THEN (Select top 1 replacement_manufacturer 
            from dbo.test_data 
            where id = abs(checksum(NewID()))%10)
    ELSE Replacement_Manufacturer
    END
```

I'd recommend the `IF` statement, but both options would work.

Comment: Thanks Jeff! I tried your IF-solution - unfortunately now I'm receiving the error message that 'Service_Reaction_Description' in the first line is an invalid column line?! But I rechecked and I'm positive this is the right name of the column. Do I maybe have to declare the database in the beginning or create a variable?

Comment: `Service_Reaction_Description` is a column name, and because you are not referencing  the table in your IF statement, it won't recognise the column name. I think Jeff's Case statement example should handle this better.